# Can I install Ubuntu without an EFI partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I was recently trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 - (dual boot using two hard drives) when suddenly, when I clicked "install now", a dialog box appeared telling me that I had not created an EFI partition and that if I continued with the installation anyway, I probably wouldn't be able to boot Ubuntu; So, I chose to create it, although without really knowing what it implies (in fact I had never installed using an EFI partition, until now); But it turns out that now I cannot boot from Windows 7 if I don't do it through the boot menu. Anyway, my question is the same as the title: what would have happened if I had continued with the installation without creating an EFI partition? Would everything be alright? BTW, my computer has BIOS; Although it is not very old, it is not that it is one of the latest models that have come out (it is an Acer Aspire Z3771) If I erase the EFI partition, would everything return to normal? Or even worsen the situation? Thanks for reading my question. :)

Comment: Hola! El sitio es solo en inglés, podés traducirla? De esa forma vas a conseguir más ayuda. Además corrés el riesgo de que se cierre la pregunta por no estar en inglés.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por el aviso, pensé que era multilingüe. La traduciré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### BIOS or UEFI

If you boot the Ubuntu Live ISO in BIOS it will install BIOS mode, If you Boot the Install ISO in UEFI mode it will install in UEFI mode. If you have Windows on the computer already, you want to install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows. My Windows 7 was always BIOS mode.

Comment: I guess that means I can just erase my external disk content without further concerns and try to install a newer version or a LTS one because I won't lose access to my Windows 7 disk if I do that. Am I right? By the way, sorry for being too noob.

Comment: @Ricardo XYZ - I have Windows 10, (UEFI) on one internal disk and Ubuntu 18.04, (BIOS) on another internal disk. I need to press F12 at boot to select the drive I want to boot to. When I Plug in an external drive with Ubuntu 18.04, (UEFI) on it I can boot Ubuntu and Windows from the external drive's grub. I suggest unplugging the internal Windows drive when installing to the external disk just to be absolutely safe.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do it this way. But first I'll try to boot without the external disk so I can see if it's necessary to boot Windows.

Comment: Finally everything is as it was before.